# Breeze : building metadata with the NHMetadataBuilder when using Envers

Tags: breeze

We use NHibernate.Envers extension for audit purpose. Therefore audit entities are generated on the fly, although they are not part of our business model.

But the NHMetadataBuilder calls GetMappedClass method and makes no distinction between these audit entities and our business entities. However it crashes later on for these audit entities. The type returned by GetMappedClass is System.Collections.IDictionnary, which obviously does not make any sense to be added to metadata.

For now, we are just ignoring these entities by adding a safeguard in BuildMetadata method:

```
        foreach (var meta in classMeta.Values)
        {
            if (!meta.EntityName.EndsWith("_AUD"))
            {
                AddClass(meta);
            }
        }
```

Can you think of a more generic way to do it ?

Comment: https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.server.net/pull/14

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pull request from [lnu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/687259/lnu) fixes the problem, and has been merged into the codebase.  It's available now from [github](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.server.net), and will be in the next Breeze release.

Thanks lnu.

Comment: Thanks. I wonder if that should be taken one step further though. We have encountered more entities that should not be exposed to the client, nor should they be "scanned" at all by the metadatabuilder method. Is there a way to provide a list of types to the metadatabuilder, which would then be ignored when building the metadata  ?

Comment: That's a good idea.  I was thinking of that already, but I hadn't done it because nobody had asked for it.  I'll try to get that done soon.